# Gatling doIf is always executed

Tags: kotlin, gatling

I'm trying to create a login scenario in Gatling but only if environment needs it. My problem is, the then block is being always executed.

```
val environment = object Local : Environment(
    url = "http://localhost:8080/",
    loginUrl = null,
    needsLogin =false
)


fun login() = doIf { session -> return@doIf !environment.needsLogin && session.getString(TOKEN_KEY).isNullOrEmpty() }
    .then(authenticationLogin())

private val loginBody = LoginBody(
    System.getenv("CI_PERFORMANCE_TEST_EMAIL") ?: "email",
    System.getenv("CI_PERFORMANCE_TEST_PASSWORD") ?: "pass"
)

fun authenticationLogin() = exec(
    http("POST Authentication")
        .post(environment.loginUrl!!)
        .formParam(EMAIL, loginBody.email)
        .formParam(PASSWORD, loginBody.password)
        .check(bodyString().saveAs("authResponse"))
        )
)
```

I can't see what is wrong with my code.

I've tried with: Put logs I cant see them. Put everything as false. Return false...Is always executed.

Comment: How do you define your gatling dependency in your project?

Comment: Using gradle, both as plugin dependency and library dependency.
    implementation("io.gatling:gatling-app:3.8.4")

    id("io.gatling.gradle") version "3.8.4"

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn’t set TOKEN_KEY in the Session anywhere so the condition session.getString(TOKEN_KEY).isNullOrEmpty() is always false.

Comment: Even with a return false is being executed, so that is not the case.

Comment: Try to provide a proper reproducer other people can run on their side, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example